# Como obtener registros sin duplicar usando join de 3 tablas con diferentes numeros de registros?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Hola amigos muy buenas tardes, espero y se encuentren bien, tengo un problema, necesito realizar una consulta sql de dos tablas ambas tienen registros con una mas que otra, realicé esta consulta:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    ( TVIV056_RELSERIE INNER JOIN TVIV055_INTISERIE ON 
    TVIV056_RELSERIE.CD_SERIE = TVIV055_INTISERIE.CD_SERIE )
    INNER JOIN TVIV053_INVERSION ON TVIV056_RELSERIE.CD_INVERSION = TVIV053_INVERSION.CD_INVERSION
```

El detalle que me arrojan todas las columnas y solo necesito 2 campos que son:

```
NB_CLAVE | NB_SERIE
```

Las tablas son:

tabla: TVIV055_INTISERIE

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta tabla tienen 51 registros.

Tabla TVIV053_INVERSION

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta otra tiene 22 registros

Solo necesitaria 2 columnas y hacer la combinacion.

El codigo siguiente es como tal de un map de java, ese codigo ya se va a quitar y se usaria los registros que arroje la consulta que estoy desarrollando:

```
correspondencia.put("A","101");
        correspondencia.put("B","102");
        correspondencia.put("B1","102");
        correspondencia.put("B2","102");
        correspondencia.put("B3","102");
        correspondencia.put("B4","102");
        correspondencia.put("BPR","102");
        correspondencia.put("C","102");
        correspondencia.put("DF","102");
        correspondencia.put("EFA","102");
        correspondencia.put("EXF","102");
        correspondencia.put("GPF","102");
        correspondencia.put("MB","102");
        correspondencia.put("MFA","102");
        correspondencia.put("P","102");
        correspondencia.put("PPR","102");
        correspondencia.put("PV","102");
        correspondencia.put("TF","102");
        correspondencia.put("UHN","102");
        correspondencia.put("B","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-1","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-2","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-3","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-4","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-5","103");
        correspondencia.put("B-6","103");
        correspondencia.put("DM","103");
        correspondencia.put("E","103");
        correspondencia.put("E1","103");
        correspondencia.put("E2","103");
        correspondencia.put("EC","103");
        correspondencia.put("EXM","103");
        correspondencia.put("IF","103");
        correspondencia.put("TM","103");
        correspondencia.put("TM1","103");
        correspondencia.put("DNC","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC1","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC2","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC3","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC4","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC5","104");
        correspondencia.put("NC6","104");
        correspondencia.put("NCC","104");
        correspondencia.put("TNC","104");
        correspondencia.put("TNC1","104");
        correspondencia.put("B","105");
        correspondencia.put("EX","105");
        correspondencia.put("F","107");
        correspondencia.put("GB","108");
```

Pero el problema que me regresa muchas filas repetidas en una de las columnas, espero y me puedan ayudar, mas adelante que obtenga lo que necesito lo meteria a un metodo y de ahi a un hashmap en java, pero primero quiero desarrollar la consulta, espero y me puedan ayudar, quedo al pendiente.

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Deberias poner la estructuras de la tabla con ejemplo para que se entienda mejor

Comment: Creo que sería bueno que leas qué es lo que hace un `CROSS JOIN`, porque en efecto es simplemente un producto cartesiano entre las tablas

Comment: Hola amigos, ya edite mi pregunta que con esto me pueda explicar mejor, quedaré al pendiente de sus comentarios saludos.

Comment: Hola Amigos, perdon por la demora, ya volvi a editar mi pregunta y cambie la consulta que realicé, solo que quisiera 2 campos en especificos, espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, saludos

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que no hay forma de relacionar las dos tablas.  La columna NB_LARGO seria la que se puede relacionar con NB_CLAVE, pero tiene la frase 'ASOCIAR A CLAVE' lo cual ironicamente no permite asociarla.  Creo que el diseño de las tablas es incorrecto.  Deberias de crear una llave foranea para poder hacer lo que quieres.

Comment: a tu código le falta la condición de join

Comment: En el codigo de OP no hay condicion en el join, por lo que asumo que es un NATURAL JOIN.

Comment: entonces necesitas escribir que es un natural join en tu código

Comment: Hola amigos, ya edite la pregunta y añadi las tablas involucradas con natural join ya hice la prueba y me salieron los mismos registros repetidos, quedo al pendiente y si falta algo que no se entienda con gusto lo pongo, saludos

Comment: Que columna es la que se repite? Hay alguna columna que se refiera a la otra tabla?

Comment: Hola, ya edite la pregunta de nuevo de la consulta que puse junto a los registros que me arroja y la que se repite es la columna "NB_CLAVE"

Comment: ya edite mi respuesta

Comment: Hola Amigos, perdon por la demora, ya volvi a editar mi pregunta y cambie la consulta que realicé, solo que quisiera 2 campos en especificos, espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Sale amigos, ya termine la consulta, por si alguien la necesita y les sirva de ejemplo:

```
SELECT  TVIV055_INTISERIE.NB_SERIE, TVIV053_INVERSION.NB_CLAVE
FROM
    ( TVIV056_RELSERIE INNER JOIN TVIV055_INTISERIE  ON 
    TVIV056_RELSERIE.CD_SERIE = TVIV055_INTISERIE.CD_SERIE )
    INNER JOIN TVIV053_INVERSION  ON TVIV056_RELSERIE.CD_INVERSION = TVIV053_INVERSION.CD_INVERSION
```

Saudos cordiales.